# Cakephp 2.x does not login manually

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to integrate facebook authentication to my Cakephp 2.2.4 app and once the facebook authentication is done, I am trying to create the user and login the user manually, I see that  though the below code is creating a auth session, i.e., $this->Auth->user() contains all the data , it is not logging the user into the app, i.e, I am not able to access other functions of the app

```
$user = $this->User->findById($user_id);
        $this->Auth->login($user);
```

this is what I am using to manually login and the user saved does not contain a username and password

this is in my AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
'Session',
'Auth'=>array(
     'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'dashboard'),
     'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'login'),
     'authError'=>'You can\'t access that page',
     'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
        ),'Basic'),
     'authorize'=>array('controller')
    ),
'RequestHandler'    
);

public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'),'Html','Form');

public function isAuthorized($user){
    return TRUE ;
}

public function beforeFilter(){

    // $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    // $this->set('logged_in',$this->Auth->loggedIn());
    // $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
}
```

}

Comment: If it's creating $this->Auth->user() data, I believe that means they ARE logged in. But logging in does not by default just grant permissions to everything site-wide.  Supply more code of how you're granting permissions to those that are logged in.

Comment: dave I have given the appcontroller code above, yes $this->Auth->loggedIn() is showing true in that particular action i.e, the action to where the app get's redirected after facebook authentication but in other actions $this->Auth->loggedIn() shows false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was nothing to do with the cakephp app but the plugin which i was using for facebook, which did not post data

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$this->Auth->login($user['User']);
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier and other ways also, it is showing that is logged in but not able to access any of the actions

Comment: i have the same experience with cakephp 3.7.9 i tried to use the setUser function but the $this->Auth->User is only avaliable on the same page where it was called

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Auth component still refer to username field for authentication instead of email. You can try change to username.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a Plugin that uses Facebook oAuth as an authentication object for Auth Component. If you want an already-built solution that uses server-side Facebook login, please check my website: http://marianofino.github.com/Facebook-Plugin-for-CakePHP/